# UEFI Grub not finding config file

Tags: shell, configuration, grub, uefi

I need to boot Windows and two other Linux distors using Grub. So, I have installed Grub on UEFI partition with a dedicated partition for storing the files used by Grub using the following command.

```
sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt/efi --root-directory=/mnt/grub --bootloader-id=Grub --uefi-secure-boot --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda
```

`/dev/sda1` mounted on `/mnt/efi` is my EFI partition, and `/dev/sda2` mounted on `/mnt/grub` is the partition intended for Grub files.

However upon booting Grub is seemingly unable to find the grub.cfg file I placed at `/mnt/grub`, and shows the default Grub shell. I am able to manually recover my system by typing either `configfile /efi/Grub/grub.cfg` or `configfile (hd0,gpt2)/grub/grub.cfg`.

Here are some of my files

```
$ sudo tree /mnt/efi/EFI
/mnt/efi/EFI
├── Grub
│   ├── BOOTX64.CSV
│   ├── fbx64.efi
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   ├── grubx64.efi
│   ├── mmx64.efi
│   └── shimx64.efi
└── Microsoft
    |...


$ sudo tree /mnt/grub/grub
/mnt/grub/grub
├── fonts
│   └── unicode.pf2
├── grub.cfg
├── grubenv
└── x86_64-efi
    |...

$ sudo cat /mnt/efi/EFI/Grub/grub.cfg
search.fs_uuid 3110d895-a376-484a-8dba-e0475b9a977c root hd0,gpt2
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disklabel type: gpt

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     526335    524288   256M EFI System
/dev/sda2      526336     657407    131072    64M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3      657408     690175     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4      690176  563607551 562917376 268.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   563607552  697825279 134217728    64G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6   697825280  966260735 268435456   128G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7   966260736  983037951  16777216     8G Linux swap
/dev/sda8   983037952 1117254748 134216797    64G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  1117255680 1385691135 268435456   128G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda10 1385691136 1402468350  16777215     8G Linux swap
```

I feel like there is some trivial mistake I am making, but I have spent too much time on this.

Comment: What grub did you install. Ubuntu's grubx64.efi has something hard coded that also need /EFI/ubuntu & the files in that folder.

Comment: I used Grub packages included in both Peppermint OS and Gparted Live. Both are Debian based. May the debain package be hardcoded too?

Comment: Really only know Ubuntu's grub and its issues.

Comment: I have installed just grub to flash drives, but add the --removable parameter to make it complete with /EFI/Boot. But still have to add my own grub.cfg. I used it primarily to make a grub loopmount bootable set of ISO files as a repair flash drive.  That uses the external UEFI boot of /EFI/Boot, but most internal UEFI can also use the as a drive or fallback boot entry.

Comment: So you are suggesting to add the --removable option? I might try that.

Comment: However, the docs say --removable just makes grub put its binaries in /EFI/Boot. This wouldn't help me as I can already succefully run the grub efi binary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that GRUB loads `grub.cfg` from the ESP using an absolute path.  Perhaps GRUB can't tell which directory it was loaded from.

In the case of Debian that path is `/EFI/debian/grub.cfg`.

You can use this command to look for paths that a particular `.efi` executable might be using:

```
strings /boot/efi/EFI/devuan/grubx64.efi | less '+/EFI\/'
```

You might need to use a different path from that above to your `.efi` executable obviously.

[This](https://bugs.devuan.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=551) seems to be a related bug.

Copying the `grub.cfg` to the expected path seems to work:

```
cd /boot/efi/EFI/
mkdir debian
cp devuan/grub.cfg debian/
```

Your commands and paths may differ of course.  And if `grub.cfg` changes then the copy will need updating since FAT file systems don't support links.  Mine looked like this though, so it looks like it won't change much:

```
search.fs_uuid $root_fs_uuid root mduuid/$array_uuid 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

After battling a similar issue yesterday, I was able to find a solution that might help you as well. My `/boot` is on ext4 and my `grub.cfg`, like yours, was redirecting the EFI binary to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

To fix this issue, I manually copied `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/` instead of using the "configfile" redirect that grub-install adds.

Is it possible that the grub EFI binary is unable to read the `grub.cfg` on an ext4? Or perhaps it is a path issue as Neil Stockbridge suggested?

EDIT: It might also be helpful to share what I was seeing before making this change. Grub shell was loading and I was able to use commands to launch Ubuntu 22.04, the Grub menu was just not displaying.